# jsf difference between implicit objects cc and component

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

Maybe this is a dumb question, but I use

```
cc
```

to refer to the composite component, for instance cc.attrs.randomAttr but I have also seen the

```
component
```

implicit object and I have used it because I was told to but I don't really understand what it is for. Can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cc` refers to the top level composite component that is being processed at the time of evaluation.

`component` simply is the ui component being processed.

So when inside a composite component, `cc` refers to the 'parent' component, while `component` when used on an individual component refers to that particular instance. Or for *simple* cases:

`cc` == `component.getCompositeComponentParent(component)`, with component being a component of which the composite component is build.

E.g. consider the following composite component:

```
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"    
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
>
    <cc:interface/>

    <cc:implementation>

        <h:outputText value="Own ID: #{component.id}, parent composite ID: #{cc.id}" /> <br/>
        <h:outputText value="Own ID: #{component.id}, parent composite ID: #{cc.id}" />

    </cc:implementation>    

</html>
```

Using this on a Facelet will print 2 different "own" IDs, namely the ones of the two outputText components, while the composite ID will be the same on both lines.

Note that things may become a little more complicated when multiple nestings of composite components are involved.

Comment: very ilustrative answer. Thanks arjan! That example really helped me out.