# How can you access the second level parent composite component in a hierarchy of nested CCs?

Tags: jsf, parent, el, composite-component

In [jsf difference between implicit objects cc and component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124961/jsf-difference-between-implicit-objects-cc-and-component/5127555#5127555) it says:

> `cc` refers to the top level composite component that is being processed at the time of evaluation.

In a hierarchy of nested composite components, how would I access say the second level parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composite components are inherently [naming containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html). You can get the [namingcontainer's](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getNamingContainer()) [parent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getParent()) as follows:

```
#{cc.namingContainer.parent}
```

And its namingcontainer parent as follows:

```
#{cc.namingContainer.parent.namingContainer.parent}
```

Etc.

Comment: Thanks! But wouldn't I rather need the children of the #{cc} since it says that `cc` refers to the **top level** composite component in the question I linked? Am I interpreting "top level composite component" correctly as referring to the topmost composite component in a nested hierarchy?

Comment: Nope, it refers to `<cc:implementation>` in current context.

Comment: Then why does it say "refers to the **top level** composite component" in the original stack item? why is the "top level" modifier even used?

Comment: I'd say it's a terminology mistake.