# What does cc.attrs.id do in jsf-2?

Tags: jsf-2

I'm new in javascript and i come here to ask you something i don't understand. In many js's files, I see line like that : "id=#{cc.attrs.id}". I suppose that the attribute "id" take a value which is in id variable. The problem is, many times, I don't find cc folder or file. What is cc ?

Thanks for your response and have a nice day !

Comment: It's impossible to know what `cc` is with the information you've provided. `id=#{cc.attrs.id}` is not valid JS syntax so your code is probably using some library or framework with proprietary syntax.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I use a jsf framework.

Comment: I see some information on this website https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/ .

Comment: This has nothing to do with Javascript

Comment: Yes, I discover web technologies step by step. I belived it was in relation.

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124961/jsf-difference-between-implicit-objects-cc-and-component

Comment: You are NOT using Javascript, You are using JSF (Java Server Faces) - Java got nothing to do with Javascript! `#{cc.attrs.id}` in JSF is called an `EL-Expression` and refers to the defined attribute `id` of the composite component (cc) wherein the EL-Expression is called.